# Reply to won't work on php form submitting to itself

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I can't get the reply to function to work on a contact form that submits to itself.

The BCC is working fine. Any help is appreciated.

```
$to = 'email@email.com';  
$subject = ''.$_POST['emailsubject'].''; 



$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

$headers .=  'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email'].''; 

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$headers .= 'Bcc: email@email.com' . "\r\n";


mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers); $sendMessage = true; unset($_POST); } } ?> <?php if($invalidCaptcha) { ?>
```

Comment: From one Fred to another, read the manual => **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php** - As a sidenote: `'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();` is broken. That's why it's ignoring the line above it.

Comment: seems like you're missing the "\r\n"; after the $_POST['email']

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $from_add = "test@gmail.com"; 

    $to_add = "email@email.com";
    $subject = "Test Msg";

    $message="test msg.";

    $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";

if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
    {
        $msg = "Mail sent OK";
    } 
    else 
    {
       $msg = "Error sending email!";
    }   
?>
```